# Core Data sqlite file's URL is changed every time - how should I debug it?

Tags: sqlite, core-data, swift3, ios-simulator

I am very confused with Core Data in Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

I want to use DB Browser for SQLite (or any other app) to edit some of DB records. But each time I run app in iOS Simulator I got different URLs for sqlite file.

For example, it can be

```
/Users/{%MY_USER%}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{%some_id%}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{%other_id_1}/Library/Application%20Support/{%DB%}.sqlite)
```

and other time it is

```
/Users/{%MY_USER%}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{%some_id%}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{%other_id_2}/Library/Application%20Support/{%DB%}.sqlite)
```

Why is is happening? What can I do to debug and manage Core Data without pain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the iOS simulator works-- it's exactly what Apple designed it to do. It's not Core Data, because this happens with all of your app's data.

If you need to use a SQLite editor for some reason, you just have to put up with it. You can help yourself some by doing one or more of:

- Print the path when the app starts up, so you can copy and paste it.
- Get [SimPholders](https://simpholders.com), which is a Mac app designed to make dealing with the simulator easier.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna take [SQLiteFlow](https://www.sqliteflow.com/) a try.

It currently available on macOS App Store, and from it's introduction:

> Handle database file name or directory changes. This makes SQLiteFlow can work friendly with your SQLite database in iOS simulator.